# Calling a data.frame from string

Tags: r, loops

I am doing a loop and I need to subset a fixed range of the columns of a data frame. But the loop is exactly to generate the name of the data.frame that I need to extract the columns. I would like to know how can I call a data.frame from a string name. It must be something similar to `assign()` function, but I am not assigning any value to nothing, I just need to generate the name of a data.frame from a string using `paste0()` function.

Comment: `eval(parse(text = "your.object"))`

Comment: Exactly that. Thanks.

Comment: if `eval` + `parse` is the answer you're prbly asking the wrong question

Comment: He understood, then the problem must be yours.

Answer (score 7):

```
a=5
b="a"
get(b)
```

Output:

```
5
```

How I found this?  I did `help(assign)` and looked under "See also" section.